# Google Cloud Console is truncating redirect_url

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

After new Google Console was released it is truncating new and existing redirect urls. When I add new redirect url, it is showed correctly, but after page reload it is truncated again. And Web application with this redirect url is no more working, causing "redirect url mismatch". I googled and found many others found this problem. How to solve this problem or how I got workaround for that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the old console. https://code.google.com/apis/console or look for the faint grey link at the bottom of the new console page.

Comment: Thank you! the link is not working (redirecting to Cloud Console), but the small link at the bottom of page is correctly showing old console. Thank you!